# Adding *.ecw files to QGIS on Windows

Tags: gdal, qgis-2, windows, ecw

How do I add and view *.ecw raster images in QGIS 2.0 ?

Answer (score 4):

**Note:** The QGIS 64bit installer used GDAL 1.10 which has the ECW plugin included. The 32bit installer is getting updated to GDAL 1.10 with the plugin at some stage, no ETA at the moment.   The following method is only needed for the 32bit installer until it updated with the new GDAL.

I had to solve this for work so thought i should share given the QGIS 2.0 release.
It is basically a rehash of a post by [Giovanni Manghi](https://www.faunalia.eu/en/blog/2019-05-21_ecw_support) in Feb 2013 but with correct paths for .dll files.

install this package    [http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/Download.aspx?file=release-1600-gdal-1-9-2-mapserver-6-2-0\gdal-19-1600-ecw.msi](https://web.archive.org/web/20140122151049/http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/Download.aspx?file=release-1600-gdal-1-9-2-mapserver-6-2-0%5Cgdal-19-1600-ecw.msi)

once installed goto:
\Program Files\GDAL\libecwj2.dll
[image]\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dll[image]

copy libecwj2.dll  into \OQGIS Dufour\bin folder[image]

copy gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dll  into QGIS Dufour\bin\gdalplugins\1.9 Folder[image]

Then restart your computer and load QGIS 2.0

Select Layer>Add Raster Layer

Select a *.ecw file> open

Done.

Answer (score -1):

1- Download and Install GDAL 1.10.0 
http://www.kyngchaos.com/files/software/frameworks/GDAL_Framework-1.10.0-2.dmg

2- Download ECW plugin for QGIS 2.0 http://www.kyngchaos.com/files/software/frameworks/GDAL-ECW_Plugin-1.10.0-1.dmg

3- Simply Download & Install QGIS 2.0

4- Now you open ecw files in QGIS

or

I would suggest you to follow:

1- Install Gdal library on your system (If Mac use brew install gdal)

2- gdalinfo --formats|grep -i ecw to make sure that you have ecw listed in supported formats

3- Use gdal_translate command to convert ecw to tiff

4- Open tiff file in QGIS